# I need to ssh into another machine using expect and a password and start a program there, then start a program on my local machine. How can I do this?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, scripting, expect

As said in the title, I am writing a script that should run on Computer A. Computer A should `ssh` on Computer B, run Program B, then exit the `ssh` session (Program B still running on Computer B) and then run Program A on Computer A.

**I must use expect and I must use a password for ssh to accomplish this.**

Here is my try so far (it is not working):

```
#!/bin/bash

#checks to see if programA is already running

if pidof -x "programA" >/dev/null; then
    echo "Program A already running"
    exit 1
fi

spawn ssh username@{$1}
/usr/bin/expect "assword:"
send "password"
./programB & # run programB in the background
exit
./programA
```

Here is the script which is supposed to terminate the programs on both computers:

```
pkill programA
spawn ssh username@{$1}
/usr/bin/expect "assword:"
send "password"
pkill programB
exit
```

The script to start the programs doesn't work as expected. It starts both Program A and Program B on Computer A. It was also brought to my attention that I need to detach my `ssh` session because otherwise when I exit it on Computer B Program B will terminate.

Can someone provide me with the script which does what I want it to do, with explanations where I went wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This would be way easier if it was not for the password. Are you sure you cannot use public key authentication?

Comment: Try this: https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-automate-tasks-in-ssh/

Comment: @Hermann I can't use public key authentication. I must use a password.

Comment: It's probably cheating to use sshpass....

Answer (score 2):

Looks almost OK. Try the following (untested obviously)

```
#!/bin/bash

#checks to see if programA is already running

if pidof -x "programA" >/dev/null; then
    echo "Program A already running"
    exit 1
fi

expect <<EOF
 spawn ssh username@${1}
 expect "assword:"
 send "password\r"
 expect "$ "
 send "nohup ./programB &\r" # run programB in the background
 exit
EOF
./programA
```

edit: address comment about ssh username@{$1}

Comment: I understand that it has been brought over verbatim from the question, but this doesn’t look right `username@{$1}` — I’d imagine the `{ }` want removing.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what does EOF stand for in expect and what does \r do on the end of the send? Also, I think I would need to call /usr/bin/expect instead of just expect.

Comment: The \r is telling expect to send the "enter" key. The EOF goes with the <<EOF, everything between them is given to the expect program. I would expect that your PATH variable contains /usr/bin so you should be able to use expect rather than /usr/bin/expect to find the expect program. @bxm, thanks, edited.

Comment: After launching programb, I'd recommend you expect the prompt then `send "exit\r"` then `expect eof` -- that will exit from the ssh session more gracefully.